# Локализация даты и времени yii2

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

используя gridview необходимо выводить дату и время.

сейчас выглядит так: `Oct 18, 2018 12:58:00 PM`

вывожу так : `'created_at:datetime',`

а надо так: `18 октября 2018, 12:58`, именно с русским названием месяца.

пробовал задавать `formatter` в `main/config` :

```
'datetimeFormat' => 'd F Y, H:i:s',
```

но месяц не выводится, а когда пишу вместо `F` - `M`, то все работает

как привести дату к такому формату?

Comment: Вариант, в `config/web.php` добавить строку     `'language' => 'ru'` подойдёт?

Comment: у меня advanced, и нет, не подойдет. уже прописана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**
В `config/web.php` добавить строку `'language' => 'ru'`

**Вариант 2**
Использовать функции [setlocale()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) и [strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ru_RU");
echo strftime(" месяц: - %В");
```

**Вариант 3**
Для любителей поизвращаться: парсить строку даты и вручную подставлять месяц.

Comment: не работает перевод. страницу ошибки переводит, некотороые сообщения тоже, а дату - нет.

Comment: @dasauser, не поверю, что второй вариант у вас не работает. А если не работает - покажите реализацию, и ошибку\вывод

Comment: мне и не нужен второй вариант, я знаю, что в фреймворке есть встроенные методы, но как их использовать - не знаю. у меня они не работают. я ведь написал, что нужно выводить в `gridview`